# How to prevent a script being stopped by suspend?

Tags: python, linux, process

I have a python alarm clock script, which needs to wake me up at some time.When I go to bed and leave it running, the laptop I use which has Linux Mint suspends itself after some time of inactivity.How can I prevent my script from being stopped and keep it running? My laptop is in my room and I need to close its lid because its light is annoying to sleep to.Here is my script.

```
import time
import sys
import webbrowser

alarm_HH = raw_input("Enter the hour you want to wake up at\n")
alarm_MM = raw_input("Enter the minute you want to wake up at\n")

print("You want to wake up at ", alarm_HH)
while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_hour == int(alarm_HH) and now.tm_min == int(alarm_MM):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.repeatmyvids.com/watch?v=SXLplRtMNfg&kmdom=youtube")
        break

    else:
        timeout = 60 - now.tm_sec
        if raw_input("Want me to stop?"):
          break
```

[EDIT]

Ok so I figured it out.I installed python xlib module, which is a low level python library that you can install with `sudo aptitude install python-xlib`.I added a few lines of code that move the mouse pointer in order to prevent suspend, or sleep, so that my script can still work with lid closed and no input from anywhere.

```
    d = display.Display()
    s = d.screen()
    root = s.root
    root.warp_pointer(500,500)
    d.sync()
```

I added a few of these, and the code now looks like this.

```
import time
import sys
import webbrowser
from Xlib import X, display

alarm_HH = input("Enter the hour you want to wake up at\n")
alarm_MM = input("Enter the minute you want to wake up at\n")

print("You want to wake up at ", alarm_HH)
while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_hour == int(alarm_HH) and now.tm_min == int(alarm_MM):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.repeatmyvids.com/watch?v=SXLplRtMNfg&kmdom=youtube")
        break

    else:
        d = display.Display()
        s = d.screen()
        root = s.root
        root.warp_pointer(500,500)
        d.sync()

        time.sleep( 5 )
        root.warp_pointer(250,250)
        d.sync()

        time.sleep( 5 )
        root.warp_pointer(100,100)
        d.sync()

        time.sleep( 5 )
        root.warp_pointer(250,250)
        d.sync()
```

Thanks to EngHamoud for giving me the idea to move the pointer in order to prevent suspend.

Comment: This is better suited to superuser.com

Comment: You could try setting your computer to wake on lan and that way the script might execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will if terminated because the script itself you could use the `atexit` 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

if it's suspend because of the operating system "after period of time that the user haven't been active "  i had faced that problem before then i've used the module xlib to control my mouse to move it randomly to it will be active

otherwise i think you gotta figure out the correct for your os configuration

hopefully i've answered what you've wondered about

Answer (score 1):

Even in [sleep mode S1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) (your "suspend" I think), the CPU(s) stop executing instructions. So your program is no longer running -- hence cannot wake-up your computer...

You will certainly have to explore other ways of doing, such as configuring the real-time clock (which is still powered at sleep) to wake-up the computer. On embedded systems, you also have access to an hardware watchdog that could be (miss)used for that purpose. Don't know if this is available on PC.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse trick appears to work in Windows too if you want to prevent suspension of your program after leaving it "idle" for a long time.  It's doesn't appear to prevent the OS from sleeping though and pausing it that way :(  Here's my asynchronous Windows solution using the mouse move concept:

Create one of these `KeepActiveThread` objects, and call `start()` / `stop()` as needed when you have a really long running processes.

```
import win32api # pywin32
import thread
import time

OSCILLATION_FREQ_SECS = 30

class KeepActiveThread() :

    def __init__( self ) :
        self.activeId_ = None        
        self.resurrectId_ = None        

    def start( self ) :       
        if self.activeId_ is None :
            if self.resurrectId_ is None :
                self.resurrectId_ = thread.start_new_thread( 
                    self.__oscillateMouseCursor, () )             
            self.activeId_ = self.resurrectId_

    def stop( self ) :       
        self.activeId_ = None

    def __oscillateMouseCursor( self ) :           
        move = 1
        while self.activeId_ :
            move *= -1
            try:
                (x, y) = win32api.GetCursorPos()        
                win32api.SetCursorPos( (x+move, y) )        
            except: pass
            time.sleep( OSCILLATION_FREQ_SECS )                 
        self.resurrectId_ = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using ctypes:

```py
import ctypes
ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000
ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(
            ES_CONTINUOUS | \
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)
```